# Zsh crashes on specific tab completion (workon)

Tags: linux, zsh

This is an annoying bug related to ZSH and python virtualenvwrapper. I couldn't find any clue on this anywhere on the web, so I am going to make a new post in SU!

### Symptoms

1. Use ZSH, and python virtualenvwrapper is installed (so that `workon` command works)
2. Type into the shell, `% workon <TAB>` to trigger tab-completion of available virtual environments.
3. Then, ZSH crashes and the current shell is closed unexpectedly.

Why does this happen? Who is the culprit, zsh or virtualenvwrapper?

### Diagnostics

AFAIK, zsh is suspicious, since we can find segmentation fault log messages.

```
Segfault happend at: 0x452005 <popheap+85>: mov 0x18(%r12),%rdi PC(0x00452005) ok
```

Sometimes (but hardly) works well, but almost always it is reproducible for several machines. I am now going to inspect on this, for various environments, for zsh versions, or for other configurations.

Environments in which I've experienced:

- Linux Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS (Kernel: Linux 3.2.0-54-generic x86_64)
- ZSH: zsh 4.3.17-1ubuntu1
- ***UPD1*** : Reproducible also in the latest ZSH, 5.0.2 (configured and compiled from the source)

### References

- [virtualenvwrapper issue #206 from bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper/issue/206/tab-completion-crashes-zsh-on-fresh-login) (it mentions the issue, its status is resolved since the author couldn't reproduce the bug after re-installation)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to use a current, [official zsh version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zsh/files/zsh/5.0.2/zsh-5.0.2.tar.gz/download)?

Comment: Same for other zsh versions (including 5.0.2), too. (UPD1)

Comment: This bug (together with another one) was discussed on the `zsh-workers` mailing list back in may: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2013/msg00442.html It seems, that the devs still [need input](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2013/msg00447.html) from s/b who can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is with ZSH plugin 'virtualenvwrapper' on systems with a particular virtualenvwrapper environment. For instannce; I installed manually rather than using 'pip install virtualenvwrapper.'

Removing `virtualenvwrapper' from my .zshrc seemed to work–around the issue. I would bet that reinstalling virtualenvwrapper using pip will fix the issue in many cases.